# Table navigation using JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a website that users create contents of a table and display them. I'm using Ruby on Rails to work on this project. So far I can let users create new rows and display, which is nearly a default function when building an application.

However, I need to know how to limit the number of rows, let's say 15 rows at once, then a user needs to click next button or navigation number (ex, 1,2,3...5) to call next 15 rows of data in the table.

I'm not really sure how to approach this matter.
If I can help on this, that would be a great help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is with pagination.  There are a number of gems which offer this but I find **kaminari** the most robust and flexible of these.

## Install the Kaminari Gem

https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari  -- Add to you gemfile and run `bundle install`

```
gem 'kaminari'
```

## Call the Kaminari method in the controller

In your controller, make sure the object collections uses the kaminari method.

```
@model = Model.all.order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

This is most likely pretty obvious, but just for clarity: The order by is not required for kaminari, the `page` method will take the parameters from the URL (params are added to the URL when a user clicks on a certain page number or clicks next or prev), and the `per` method is the number of records allowed on each page.

## Add pagination to your view

Now in your view - just call the pagination helper with your object to add the pagination links (Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next)

```
= paginate @model
```

You can also change the look and feel the pagination links, just read the documentation, it's pretty straighforward.

---

Since this is your first post I will also add:

WELCOME!! Thanks for your post.  New questions keep the community on their toes.

Next time you post, keep in mind that everyone here is happy to help, but if you add a few things to your post the answers will come quicker and you won't be downvoted:

- Add code snippets and samples to your post, its easier for answers to come if they can see your work and also improves answers if they can mock up code responses based on your original question, less confusion that way
- Give links to tutorials you might be using
- State what you've tried, and why it's not working as you'd expect / prefer

Comment: Thank you for your help!